# Add marker in Google Maps - Flutter

Tags: google-maps, flutter, google-maps-markers

I need to create some Marker in my app, I get the latitude and longitude by API. How can I will show these markers?

My getPosts code:

```
Future<List<Orders>> getPosts() async {
Response response = await http.get(url);
//print(response.body);
if(response.statusCode == 200){
  List<dynamic> body = jsonDecode(response.body);
  List<Orders> orders = body.map((dynamic item) => Orders.fromJson(item)).toList();
  return orders;
} else {
  throw "Can't get orders";
}
```

My class Order:

```
class Orders {

final String id;
final String nameRestaurant;
final String address;
final String lat;
final String long;
final bool delivered;
final String orderId;
final String phone;

Orders({@required this.id, @required this.nameRestaurant, @required this.address, @required this.lat,
  @required this.long, @required this.delivered, @required this.orderId, @required this.phone});

factory Orders.fromJson(Map<dynamic, dynamic> json){
  return Orders(
    id: json['id'] as String,
    nameRestaurant: json['nameRestaurant'] as String,
    address: json['address'] as String,
    lat: json['lat'] as String,
    long: json['long'] as String,
    delivered: json['delivered'] as bool,
    orderId: json['orderId'] as String,
    phone: json['phone'] as String
  );
 }
}
```

I followed some tutorials but all of them add marker in onTap function but it don't works to me

Answer (score 20, accepted):

To add a list of simple markers, first create a list of markers:

```
List<Marker> _markers = <Marker>[];
```

Then add Marker to this list:

```
    _markers.add(
      Marker(
      markerId: MarkerId('SomeId'),
      position: LatLng(38.123,35.123),
      infoWindow: InfoWindow(
      title: 'The title of the marker'
      )
     )
   );
```

Consider that in `infoWindow` you can also add subtitle and other stuff.
Finally add the google map widget:

```
GoogleMap(
      initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
        target: LatLng(38.9647,35.2233),
        zoom: 9.0,
      ),
      mapType: MapType.normal,
      markers: Set<Marker>.of(_markers),
      onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
        _controller.complete(controller);
      },
    )
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all create a map of markers as follows:

```
  Map<MarkerId, Marker> markers = <MarkerId, Marker>{MarkerId('marker_id_1'):Marker(
markerId: MarkerId('marker_id_1'),
position: LatLng(30.0444, 31.235),
infoWindow: InfoWindow(title: 'marker_id_1', snippet: '*'),
onTap: () {
  //_onMarkerTapped(markerId);
  print('Marker Tapped');
},
onDragEnd: (LatLng position) {
  print('Drag Ended');
},  )};
```

Then add googleMap anywhere you want as follows

```
GoogleMap(
                          mapType: MapType.normal,
                          //initialCameraPosition: cairo,
                          markers: Set<Marker>.of(markers.values),
                          //onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
                          //  _controller.complete(controller);
                          //},
                        )
```